Can we create the tag 'bitcoinjs' again?
This was raised  a while back, but the tag seems to have gotten deleted.
I'd like to tag this question as well as all of these.

Don't know how that happened but I have added it back. Someone feel free to add a tag wiki for it.

I tried it on the same question.

Creating the new tag [bitcoinjs] is not allowed since the tag
  [bitcoinj] already exists. If you think this new tag should be
  allowed, raise it on meta.

Who has the privilege to (re-)create it?

Diamond moderators, methinks.
